# C# loop on fraction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops

> I need someone to give me an idea on how to go on about this problem.Using a loop to calculate the fraction , There is no common value.I want to get the sum

Eg for fraction :

```
1  1/5  1/10  1/15  1/20 … 1/290  1/295  1/300
```

code snippet:-

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=1;i<=60 ;i++)
{
   int sum=1
}
```

Comment: You want to get the sum of `1/(5*i)` for `i` in `1:60`? You know that's a geometric series, which means there's a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) to get the result instantly

Comment: To start with, the sum is not an integer, so you probably want a `float`. Beyond that, it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: @JohnPerry I would suggest decimal for such accurate values instead of float

Comment: @IpsitGaur Fair enough; I'm not that familiar with C#, but in any case there's a problem with `int sum`.

Comment: @IpsitGaur: What makes you think that a decimal type can store the terms more accurately than a `double`?

Comment: @Rafalon - it's not geometric! Geometric series' denominators increase exponentially. This is increasing linearly.

Comment: @AlexReinking that's what I realized 3 minutes ago as my comment on Bathsheba's answer demonstrates. But hey, thanks for pointing it out anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These sort of problems are actually surprisingly non-trivial due to issues with working with floating point, and decimal types for that matter.

Accepting that you want a loop solution for this (a closed form solution for `n` terms does exist), first note that your series can be written as

```
1 + 1/5(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/60)
```

Then note that a good rule of thumb when working with floating point types is to add the small terms first.

So an algorithm would be of the form

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 60; i >= 1; --i){
    sum += 1.0 / i;
}
sum = sum / 5 + 1;
```

Note the `1.0` in the numerator; that's there to defeat *integer division*.

Reference: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Or `double sum = (1-Math.Pow(0.2,60))/(1-0.2);` right?

Comment: @Rafalon: Or just write out the answer as a constant! I think the OP wants a loop.

Comment: You mean `sum / 5 + 1`

Comment: @Rafalon, yes that **could** be the thing what if the question state to do it with a loop ?

Comment: @DragandDrop & Bathsheba, that's right, I missed the "*Using a loop*" part

Comment: @AlexReinking: No I don't, unless my rewritten form is incorrect.

Comment: @Rafalon, this should have been an answer btw ^^. beening able to out side of the box seeing the general pattern is a good thing and will make a great answer with little code and little explanation. And We like to see math use here. To render a non trivial issue trivial. So we can even compare the result of both.

Comment: @Bathsheba - It _is_ incorrect. OP wanted `1 + 1/5 + 1/10 + ... + 1/300`. You gave `5 + 1/5 * (1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/60) = 5 + 1/5 + 1/10 + ... + 1/300`.

Comment: @AlexReinking: Oops. Fixed. Let's publish jointly. And I'll upvote your answer for good feelings!

Comment: @Bathsheba - works for me

Comment: @DragandDrop I was on my way of writing that, but I realized I made a mistake, it's not geometric, as you do not multiply by `0.2` at every step as I thought, this would have been `1 + 1/5 + 1/25 + 1/75 ...`

Answer (score 3):

͏Since you asked for a hint:

```
float sum = 1.0;
for (int i = 5; i <= ??; i += ??) {
    sum += 1.0/i;
}
```

What goes in place of the `??`s?

Comment: It's naughty to add the large terms first when working with floating point.

Comment: @Bathsheba - It doesn't matter one iota in this case. The relative error between the two directions is `2.27e-16`

Comment: But it's still bad practice. If this finds its way into a language where the `double` allows you freedom to mess about with the exponent and mantissa, it *could* matter.

Comment: I'm not really looking to discuss the finer points of floating-point best practice when OP is having trouble forming the loop in the first place. But you raise a fair point.

Comment: @Bathsheba interesting... Could you explain "why" this is a bad practice? Or give some reference to read, I would like to learn more about that :)

Comment: ^ Floating point is most accurate when adding numbers of similar magnitude. In floating point `1 + 1e-16` is exactly `1`, but you can actually express `1e-16 + 1e-16`. If you have a lot of small values, they could add up to a bigger one, which would be more accurate if the terms of your sum have a high dynamic range.

Comment: @DamienFlury: in floating point, adding a very small number to a very big number can be a no-op. So you want to give the small numbers chance in a sum of contributing to the final total. Therefore add them first.

Comment: @AlexReinking and Bathsheba Alright, I think this makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
    double sum=1;
    for(int i=5; i<=300; i+=5)
        sum += (double) 1 / i;
```

The value of sum will be 1.93597408259035